# Why does adding white noise improve the calculation of frequency of a sine wave in the time domain?

Tags: noise, white-noise

I created short audio files with a sine wave (tone) having a set frequency, and added varying white noise to it generated by a random number generator.
I wanted to code and test the simple algorithm described in IEEE-STD-1057 & 1241 to calculate the frequency in the time domain by measuring the times the amplitudes flip sign.
This works well when white noise has been added, but is less accurate when white noise is absent. What's the reason why the added white noise improves accuracy?

Just guessing; might this have something to do with dithering?
The difference between a smooth (analog) sine wave and the digitized one is a sawtooth with varying amplitudes - the quantization error.
Dithering is the addition of noise in order to smooth the digitized recording.
Digitizing an analog source causes quantization errors, and dithering compensates for that in some way.

Comment: could you post your code for both algorithms?

Comment: Are you doing enough simulations per noise level? In a single test it could be. In many, it doesn't should be like that.

Comment: It's possible that without noise, your matrices become almost singular creating some numerical issues

Comment: The code is way too long to post here. I did many simulations to uncover the trends. No matrices involved in the calculations - just plain elementary arithmetic operations.

Comment: Aren't they least-squares fit algorithms ? You usually have an overdetermined set of equations that you solve... If it smells like matrices, it's probably matrices.

Comment: This is the bit to calculate the frequency only - no matrices involved here. Calculating the remaining three parameters does involve matrices, but that's not what my question is about.

Comment: Ok, can you extract the frequency calculation from your algorithm and post it ?

Comment: I put the simulation script (PHP) on my Box : https://app.box.com/s/2nud2hu93yrq8rnv4vqyrdxsmu5mb1lz
I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with this code, it does what I expected, the results show a phenomenon I would like to know the explanation for.
BTW, the comments in the script are in my native tongue Dutch.

Comment: @Petoetje59 that phenomenon is *because* of your code – there's no doubt about that! The question now is whether the phenomenon can be explained by the underlying approach or by your specific implementation. Sadly, your PHP code is practically illegible; I especially can't make out what the actual estimation part is, and what is just you know, data handling (especially because PHP really doesn't have the data types and functionality to make handling sampled signals easy). As a code reviewer (acting as if I didn't care about what the code does, just what it looks like), I'd say you

Comment: forgot to apply proper code formatting, and while you were very diligent in commenting your code, you didn't do it in a language your readers understand :) So, please fix the code – things like multiple statements on a line, inconsistent indentation, lack of space between arguments etc are not necessary with a modern editor and only make *your* life harder. Then, extract things into functions, and tell us which function actually does the estimate. Refactor! Also, consider using a different tool than PHP, which is really not well-suited for this kind of task.

Comment: I think you are right. I would suggest you will look into the subject of Dithering - a way to avoid computation/quantization issues when you are processing Pure Sine Waves.

Comment: Glad to see someone is confirming my suspicions. After reading up on the dithering concept I'm now convinced that this indeed is the explanation for the noticed phenomenon.

Comment: This could be Stochastic Resonance, see Moss et al Clinical Neurophysiology 115 (2004) 267–281 which is a nice review. There must be more recent stuff but I haven't searched.

Comment: Interesting. There's also a Wikipedia article on stochastic resonance, and it states that this is related to dithering.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to demonstrate how dithering improves accuracy in quantized systems (which includes the approach the OP used to estimate frequency) is to consider this example of a system that is quantized to integers with "truth" being some fraction in between such as $1.4$. With no noise added, our result would always be $1$. If we added enough noise with a uniform distribution of one quantization level, and could also oversample such that we can average the result- then we can see how in this case 60% of the samples will result in $1$ and 40% in $2$ resulting in $1.4$ on average.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a zero crossing algorithm, and depending on the relationship between sine frequency and sampling frequency, I can easily see systematic errors when estimating frequency from zero crossing rate.

Adding noise would presumably act as a dither that introduce spurious perturbations about the true (desired) mean. If you estimate frequency from the mean of several zero crossing spacings, I can see that adding noise might benefit accuracy in some cases.

Comment: This is indeed a zero crossing algorithm. FYI, frequency of the sine wave was 1000Hz, sampling frequency 5512Hz, and the results were best when white noise was present, not so for the pure digitized sine wave which always resulted in 1004.0Hz, whilst the noisy ones always varied between 1000.6-1001.7Hz.